# Rally Rest API fetch conversation post by defect FormattedID

Tags: java, rest, rally

I am trying to pull discussions for a given defect. I understand from a prior question I asked that it is not possible to pull the discussion data as a property of the defect itself rather I must run a separate fetch request.

The problem is that I can not identify any query filter to use when pulling conversation posts. This leads me to believe I would have to loop through every single conversation post and try to find the matching defect number in the actual data returned which would be highly inefficient.

Rather I would prefer to simply run a query fetch for each defect that uses a query filter for the formatted ID that will only return the conversation posts that apply for that defect.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class ExtractFull {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"), "_myapikey");
        restApi.setApplicationName("DANA Example");
        restApi.setProxy(new URI("http://myproxy:8080"), "username", "pass");




        System.out.println("Querying Rally for defects, this may take some time");

        try {

            QueryRequest defectRequest = new QueryRequest("ConversationPost");
            defectRequest.setPageSize(2000);
            defectRequest.setLimit(5000);
            QueryFilter filter = new QueryFilter("FormattedID","=","DE10101");
            defectRequest.setQueryFilter(filter);

            defectRequest.setFetch(new Fetch());

            QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(defectRequest);


            for(JsonElement result: queryResponse.getResults()){

                System.out.println(result);


            }
        } finally {
            restApi.close();
        }

    }

}
```

This code doesn't work. I assume because "FormattedId" isn't a valid object of the "ConversationPost" type. I don't know if it's possible to filter for parent defect ID when querying a conversation post but that is what I need to do.

Specifically the code I am referring to is here:

```
  QueryRequest defectRequest = new QueryRequest("ConversationPost");
                defectRequest.setPageSize(2000);
                defectRequest.setLimit(5000);
                QueryFilter filter = new QueryFilter("FormattedID","=","DE10101");
                defectRequest.setQueryFilter(filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve this issue on my own. The problem was that I was attempting to use "QueryRequest" without having a valid "type" to pass to the constructor.

The correct solution was to use "GetRequest" with the path to the defect discussion page being passed as the url (without requiring me to set an object type in the constructor). This returned a GetRequest object which contained a result set with all of the conversation posts.

```
 GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(discussionURL);
            GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
```

The "discussion url" did not contain the "https://rally1.rallydev.com" which was declared when creating the rallyApi - the discussionURL variable contains the entire defect discussion page URL but without the above rally api url so for example "**/slm/webservice/v2.0/Defect/106032660792/Discussion**"

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard WSAPI, I can query like this:

> (Artifact.FormattedID = "US123")